# How to get and store all input values of TextInput fields onSubmit function in ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput, react-state

Here is my code untill now:

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View as SafeAreaView, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './stylesheet';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-web';

export default class FetchSoccerMatfches extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    loading: true,
    matches: [],
  };
  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state1 = {
      matchscores: [{homeScore: "", awayScore: ""}]
    };
  }

  handleChange(homeScore, awayScore) {
      this.setState({
      homeScore: {...this.state1.matchscores.homeScore},
      awayScore: {...this.state1.matchscores}
    });
    console.log(this.state1)
  }

  // handleSubmit = event =>  {
  //   console.log(this.state1)
  // }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '1ee01fa5e8msh6746fc88b24d9f6p18d6e0jsn1d11e8f67917',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    }
    
    
    const response = await fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures?league=39&season=2022&round=Regular Season - 7', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
      const myMatches = response.response;
      const MatcheLength = myMatches.length;
      console.log(response);
      // for(let i = 0; i < MatcheLength.length; i++){
        this.setState({matches: myMatches, loading: false});                 
  }
    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return <div>loading...</div>;
      }
  
      if (!this.state.matches.length) {
        return <div>didn't get a person</div>;
      }

      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Text style = {styles.h2Style}>
            Place a bet
          </Text>
          {
            this.state.matches.map(matches => {
              return(
                <SafeAreaView key={matches.fixture.id} style={styles.paragraphHomePage}>
              <Text style={styles.testing}>
                <Text style={styles.teamNames}>{matches.teams.home.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.vs}>-</Text>
                <Text style={styles.teamNames}>{matches.teams.away.name} {'\n'}</Text> 
                <TextInput
          key={matches.fixture.id}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          placeholder="Tore "
          placeholderTextColor="#d3d3d3"
          numeric
          value={this.state1.matchscores.homeScore}
          onChangeText={(homeScore) => this.handleChange(homeScore)}
        />
          <Text style={styles.vs}>-</Text>
          <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          placeholder="Tore"
          placeholderTextColor="#d3d3d3"
          numeric
          keyboardType={'numeric'}
          onChangeText={(awayScore) => this.handleChange(awayScore)}
        />
              </Text>
              </SafeAreaView>
              )
            })
          }
                        <SafeAreaView>
              <Button
        title="Press me"
        style= {styles.placebetbutton}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
      />
              </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }   
}
```

So when the user clicks on the button ("CLICK ME" button), i am facing trouble storing all input data into an array (matchscores).. i simply want to store data as for example:
matchId: xxx, homeScore: 1, awayScore: 0, and so for every single soccer match. Any help would be appreciated :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgBp3.png)

Answer (score 0):

For store all textinput value you can use formik for that
https://formik.org/docs/overview

Check how we can store all form data in onSubmit

Comment: i basically need some fuction which is going to loop through every single textinput component and store its value into an array. I think formik is not going to bring me any further :/ But thanks for your help